# Sending a UserID and ChatroomID to Microsoft botconnector

Tags: bots, botframework, botconnector

I have a bot hosted on Heroku talking with Directline channel of Bot connector. I want to send my bot information about the user it's talking to. How do I do that? I can't find any information about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Directline is enabled you can use GET and POST requests to *chat* with the bot. When doing so, set the botUserData field as some serializable object which will persist throughout the conversation. You can then deserialize this object within the bot, at the server side, at any moment by accessing it from message.botUserData .

If you want to know how to make requests via Direct Line refer this [API reference](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/#/)